# Tree searching algorithm: how to determine quickly if A has a sure-to-win strategy

Tags: algorithm, tree

The original question goes like this: There are 99 stones, A and B are playing a game that, each one take some stones in turn, and each turn one can only take 1, 2, 4, or 6 stones, the one take the last stone wins. If A is the first one to take stones, how many stones shall A take in the first turn?

This seems a quite complex tree searching quiz, listing out all the branches, then work it bottom up: the leaf with A taking the last stone is marked as "win"; for the intermediate node that whatever strategies B might take, if A always has a way to reach a node marked as "win", this node is also marked as "win".

But this approach  is quite time consuming. Is there any smart algorithm to check out if A has a "guaranteed to win" strategy?

Comment: The question title should be informative.

Comment: @sashoalm edited, is it ok now?

Comment: This game is also known as Nim - google that.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I think it's slightly different: Nim game allow player to take certain stones less than a number, but this game only allows 1, 2, 4, and 6. Would it be different?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError - it's not exactly Nim. If you're saying it can be reduced to Nim, I don't think that's immediately obvious.

Comment: Are there always 99 stones, or do you want a general solution for `n` stones?

Comment: @IVlad a generalized solution of course is even better.. 99 is killing me already

Comment: @athos Yes, it's good now.

Comment: Okay, it's _akin_ to Nim, then.

Comment: @athos Sounds like discrete optimization to me. You start from bottom - from the winning positions, and work your way to the initial position in the game. When you have winning position, any position that can lead to it is also a winning one.

Comment: The premises for this question is slightly wrong. To check if A *has* a winning strategy is quite impossible, you need to just ask A. To check if A *can win using the winning strategy known here* is something else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**O(n) solution**

If we start with 1, 2, 4 or 6 stones, `A` will always win, because he'll just take them all in the first move.

If we start with 3, `A` will lose no matter what he does, because regardless of whether he takes 1 or 2, `B` will take 2 or 1 next and win.

If we start with 5, `A` will win by taking 2 first, thus sending `B` to the case above, where he starts with 3 stones.

If we start with 7, `A` will win by taking `4`, sending `B` to the same case with `3`.

If we start with 8, `A` will lose no matter what he does: whatever he takes, he will send `B` to a winning position.

If we start with 9, `A` can take 1 and send `B` to the situation with 8, causing him to lose.

If we start with 10, `A` can take 2 and send `B` to the situation with 8 again, causing him to lose.

By now, it should become quite obvious how you can incrementally build an `O(n)` solution: let `win[i] = true if i stones are winnable for the first person to move`

We have:

```
win[1] = win[2] = win[4] = win[5] = win[6] = true, win[3] = false
win[x > 6] = not (win[x - 6] and win[x - 4] and win[x - 2] and win[x - 1])
```

For example:

```
win[7] = not (win[1] and win[3] and win[5] and win[6])
       = not (true and false and true and true)
       = not false
       = true
```

Compute this up until the number you're interested in and that's it. No trees involved.

**O(1) solution**

By looking carefully at the above solution, we can derive a simple constant time solution: note that `A` can only lose if he sends `B` to a winning position no matter what he does, so if `k - 6, k - 4, k - 2, k - 1` are all winning positions.

If you compute `win` for a few values, the pattern becomes obvious:

```
win[k] = false if k = 3, 8, 11, 16, 19, 24, 27, 32...
=> win[k] = false iff k mod 8 == 3 or k mod 8 == 0
```

For 99, `99 mod 8 = 3`, so `A` does not have a sure winning strategy.

Comment: I think I found a more useful sequence (answer below), and the length of the cycle is 56, which is divided by 8. Just for curiosity, how can you come up with number 8?

Comment: @PhamTrung - I noticed that `win[k] = false` when `k mod 8 = 0`, but also in other cases. Then I noticed that those cases only happen when `k mod 8 = 3`, so I combined the two.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so we can see that:

Every turn, number of stones can be taken is **less than 7**, so the result should be related to **modulus 7**.

So, for n < 1000, I have printed out the sequence of number of stones that makes the first person win, modulus 7, and it is a truly repeated cycle.

```
1 2 4 5 6 0 2 3 5 6 0 1 3 4 6 0 1 2 4 5 0 1 2 3 5 6 1 2 3 4 6 0 2 3 4 5 0 1 3 4 5 6 1 2 4 5 6 0 2 3 5 6 0 1 3 4 6 0 1 2 4 5 0 1 2 3 5 6 1 2 3 4 6 0 2 3 4 5 0 1 3 4 5 6 1 2 4 5 6 0 2 3 5 6 0 1 3 4 6 0 1 2 4 5 0 1 2 3 5 6 1 2 3 4 6 0 2 3 4 5 0 1 3 4 5 6 1 2 4 5 6 0 2 3 5 6 0 1 3 4 6 0 1 2 4 5 0 1 2 3 5 6 1 2 3 4 6 0 2 3 4 5 0 1 3 4 5 6 1 2 4 5 6 0 2 3 5 6 0 1 3 4 6 0 1 2 4 5 0 1 2 3 5 6 1 2 3 4 6 0 2 3 4 5 0 1 3 4 5 6 1 2 4 5 6 0 2 3 5 6 0 1 3 4 6 0 1 2 4 5 0 1 2 3 5 6 1 2 3 4 6 0 2 3 4 5 0 1 3 4 5 6 1 2 4 5 6 0 2 3 5 6 0 1 3 4 6 0 1 2 4 5 0 1 2 3 5 6 1 2 3 4 6 0 2 3 4 5 0 1 3 4 5 6 1 2 4 5 6 0 2 3 5 6 0 1 3 4 6 0 1 2 4 5 0 1 2 3 5 6 1 2 3 4 6 0 2 3 4 5 0 1 3 4 5 6 1 2 4 5 6 0 2 3 5 6 0 1 3 4 6 0 1 2 4 5 0 1 2 3 5 6 1 2 3 4 6 0 2 3 4 5 0 1 3 4 5 6 1 2 4 5 6 0 2 3 5 6 0 1 3 4 6 0 1 2 4 5 0 1 2 3 5 6 1 2 3 4 6 0 2 3 4 5 0 1 3 4 5 6 1 2 4 5 6 0 2 3 5 6 0 1 3 4 6 0 1 2 4 5 0 1 2 3 5 6 1 2 3 4 6 0 2 3 4 5 0 1 3 4 5 6 1 2 4 5 6 0 2 3 5 6 0 1 3 4 6 0 1 2 4 5 0 1 2 3 5 6 1 2 3 4 6 0 2 3 4 5 0 1 3 4 5 6 1 2 4 5 6 0 2 3 5 6 0 1 3 4 6 0 1 2 4 5 0 1 2 3 5 6 1 2 3 4 6 0 2 3 4 5 0 1 3 4 5 6 1 2 4 5 6 0 2 3 5 6 0 1 3 4 6 0 1 2 4 5 0 1 2 3 5 6 1 2 3 4 6 0 2 3 4 5 0 1 3 4 5 6 1 2 4 5 6 0 2 3 5 6 0 1 3 4 6 0 1 2 4 5 0 1 2 3 5 6 1 2 3 4 6 0 2 3 4 5 0 1 3 4 5 6 1 2 4 5 6 0 2 3 5 6 0 1 3 4 6 0 1 2 4 5 0 1 2 3 5 6 1 2 3 4 6 0 2 3 4 5 0 1 3 4 5 6 1 2 4 5 6 0 2 3 5 6 0 1 3 4 6 0 1 2 4 5 0 1 2 3 5 6 1 2 3 4 6 0 2 3 4 5 0 1 3 4 5 6 1 2 4 5 6 0 2 3 5 6 0 1 3 4 6 0 1 2 4 5 0 1 2 3 5 6 1 2 3 4 6 0 2 3 4 5
```

This cycle has the length is 56, so the problem can be solved in O(1) by finding the result of first 56 numbers.

Comment: I wouldn't say this is more useful though: you have to find an entire sequence instead of just taking a modulo.